# Dart: replace a string between 2 other strings

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to replace a string between 2 other strings in dart, for example :

```
var str="<!-- cells -->test<!-- cells -->";
```

the delimiters around will not change and will be always the same.

How to replace 'test' by 'test2' for example ?

Answer (score 4):

```
  var str = "<!-- cells -->test<!-- cells -->";
  var replace = 'foo';
  var counter = 0;

  final result = str.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(<!-- )(.*?)( -->)'), (m) {
    return '${m[1]}$replace${counter++}${m[3]}';
  });

  print(result);
```

Comment: thank you but this solution replaces the string around and not the string "test"

Comment: I see. I misread the question.  Changing the RegExp to `r'( -->)(.*?)(<!-- )'` should do.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found a solution quickly: replaceAllMapped